# Zapier: simple zap with javascript execution takes too long

Tags: javascript, zapier

For some reason, zap's with javascript code started working very slow.

This zap, which was created for testing, consists of Slack as a trigger, Javascript, and Slack as an action.

```
Found 1 new Public Message Posted Anywhere in Slack.
3/12/2018, 9:23:48 PM

Sent 1 new Run Javascript to Code.
3/12/2018, 9:24:36 PM

Sent 1 new Channel Message to Slack.
3/12/2018, 9:25:20 PM

Javascript code: output = [{"hello": "world"}];
```

Is there a cap limit on javascript code executions per day or something like that as I believe execution became very slow after testing?

Maybe this line in javascript action "data out" can explain it. It may be self-explanatory but I do not know what it really means.

```
runtime_meta__memory_used_mb:25
```

Subscription plan is: starter plan

Comment: Update (3/13/2018, 00:33:12 AM): now it works much faster. I am not sure if as fast as it can but much better. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

We had a brief outage this afternoon, which you can read the details of [here](https://status.zapier.com/incidents/27r1w1jmmrkp).

Typically everything runs pretty fast, so if you're seeing an issue like this, the best place to check is https://status.zapier.com!

Comment: Hi David. Ok, that explains it. Thank you for the link. I have another question. It is a bit off topic, but is it possible to have a Slack trigger for every DM / private conversations with one zap? Right now there is a trigger for only one DM.

Comment: Not currently supported. We're looking to expand conversation support in the future but have no immediate plans. I'd suggest writing into support (`contact@`) and requesting that. We log everything that comes in, so that helps us choose what to work on

Comment: Will do. Another question. This one is quite important. Is it possible to return an array from javascript action and later on access that returned variable as an array and not string? I think javascript action returns array but once you try to access it from other action, it gives you as a string (data separated with ","). Javascripts' .split() was fine until I got myself data with commas.

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) returning it as an array, you can store it as a JSON string or something and then parse it back out into a js object when you need it